# Android bound service using retrofit Message.replyto is null

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a bound service that gets a message with a replyTo value set. After calling through to the rest service on the subscribe (or error block in my case) the replyTo is null.  I checked to make sure I am returning to the same thread (main thread).  Not sure why this is happening.  Here is a snippet of code...

```
                private fun handleMessage(message: Message) {
        //message.replyTo is valid here
        disposable = serviceHandler
            .getSpaces()
            .retry(Constants.REST_RETRY)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) //new thread for call REST
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(this.looper)) //validated thread ID is the same as when the function started
            .subscribe(
                { 
                    //DO SOMETHING
                },
                { error ->
                    //message.replyTo is null
                },
                {
                    //complete 
                } )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Message object after return of handleMessage is recycled and used by other programs. RX rest call and code in subscribe is executed asynchronously in a new thread, so it can, and probably will be executed after return of handleMessage when message object is recycled and used for other purposes.

So code:

```
private fun handleMessage(message: Message) {
        Log.i("TAG", "start of handleMessage");
        disposable = serviceHandler
            .getSpaces()
            .retry(Constants.REST_RETRY)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) 
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(this.looper))
            .subscribe(
                { 
                    Log.i("TAG", "end of rest call - now using message");
                },
                { error ->
                    //message.replyTo is null
                },
                {
                    //complete 
                } )
       Log.i("TAG", "end of handleMessage - message is now free");
    }
```

Will behave:

```
start of handleMessage
end of handleMessage - message is now free  <- here message is returned to pool
end of rest call - now using message
```

To use message in subscribe make a copy of it and use that copy:

```
Message messageCopy = Message.obtain(message);
...
.subscribe({
              Log.i("TAG", "copied message" + messageCopy.what);
          })
```

Comment: NB this also applies to Xamarin if you're doing `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else out there getting the same issue.  I was able to get around this by creating a new HandlerThread and using that when creating the Handler class in my bound service.  This then handled all the messages on a non UI thread and allowed me to remove the RxJava subscribeOn and observeOn.